# C# Socket recusando conexão publica

Tags: c#, socket, ip

Estou usando o exemplo server e client abaixo para fazer uma conexão TCP via internet e no cliente retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> *Additional information: Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente*

A porta *5902* via IP publico está liberada, utilizei um outro software que abre uma conexão TCP nessa mesma porta e testando com telnet via IP publico, conectou normalmente.

### Servidor

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Server
{
    class Server
    {
        static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        private static void ThreadInfos()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Title = "Unity C# Server - Threads: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count.ToString();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Thread to show infos on console title
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadInfos));
            thread.Start();

            IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5902);
            Console.WriteLine("Local address and port : {0}", localEP.ToString());

            Socket listener = new Socket(localEP.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEP);
                listener.Listen(10);

                while (true)
                {
                    allDone.Reset();

                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),listener);

                    allDone.WaitOne();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Closing the listener...");
        }

        static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Get the socket that handles the client request.
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            // Signal the main thread to continue.
            allDone.Set();

            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.WorkSocket = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }

        public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.WorkSocket;

            // Read data from the client socket.
            int read = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            // Data was read from the client socket.
            if (read > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] read {1} bytes", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, read);
                //state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, read));
                handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                /*if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    // All the data has been read from the client;
                    // display it on the console.
                    string content = state.sb.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Read {1} bytes from socket.\n Data : {2}",
                       Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, content.Length, content);
                }*/
                handler.Close();
            }
        }

        public class StateObject
        {
            public Socket WorkSocket = null;
            public const int BufferSize = 1024;
            public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            //public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
}
```

### Cliente

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("201.35.xxx.xxx"), 5902);

            Socket s = new Socket(remoteEP.Address.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            s.Connect(remoteEP);

            Console.WriteLine("Connected, sending a few bytes...");

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test");

            while (true)
            {
                s.Send(bytes);
            }

            s.Close();
            s.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O firewall está desativado.

Comment: Descobri o problema, eu tenho um serviço(VNC viewer) que inicia junto com o Windows nessa mesma porta, alterei a porta e conectou perfeitamente. Estranho é que o framework não gerou nenhuma exception dizendo que a porta já estava em uso, vai entender.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um problema individual que não poderá ser reproduzido e não ajudará outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta dada em comentário**: O problema era causado porque o OP tem um serviço(*VNC Viewer*) que inicia junto com o Windows que usa essa mesma porta, a porta foi alterada e conectou de modo esperado.